# Ajax + JSON Decode + Slim PHP problems?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, zepto

Ok I can't seem to decode the JSON from my ajax call, which posts user data to my api, which is built in slim php..

This is my ajax..

```
var jsonData;
jsonData = [
      {
        username: "user",
        password: "pass"
      }
    ];

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/api/user/auth",
  data: {
    user: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
  },
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    alert("You are good!");
  },
  error: function(xhr, type) {
    alert("Y U NO WORK?");
  }
});
```

This is my SLIM PHP code..

```
$app->post('/user/auth', function () use ($app) {
    try {
         $requestBody = $app->request()->getBody(); //This works

         //RequestBody is: user=%5B%7B%22username%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22pass%22%7D%5D         

         $json_a = json_decode($requestBody); //This doesn't work

         print_r($json_a); //Has no output?

         $username = $json_a['user']['username']; //Therefore this doesn't work?

    } catch(Exception $e) {
         echo '{"error":{"text": "'. $e->getMessage() .'"}}';
    }
});
```

As you can see in the comments, written in the code, requestBody equals:

```
user=%5B%7B%22username%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22pass%22%7D%5D
```

However, I can't seem to decode it, as print_r($json_a) has no effect.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i think that is just an object in javascript

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$params_str = urldecode($requestBody);
parse_str($params_str, $params_arr);
$user = json_decode($params_arr['user']);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this hasn't worked. urldecode has converted the string back to "user=[{"username":"user","password":"pass"}]", however json decode hasn't converted it into an array or anything? print_r($json_a) still returns nothing. hmmm :/

Comment: The key `user=` at the start, is getting in the way. Can you pass one more variable in the data part of the ajax request and show how `$requestBody` looks.

Answer (score 2):

Youre doing it wrong... you are sending the data via post so you shoudl grab the json string from there instead of trying to manually read the request body... something like

```
$req = $app->request();
$json = json_decode($req->post('user'));
```

Now if you actually want to send a json request body thats a whole different thing, but it will require changes to your js. You need to set `processData` to false so that it does not try to encode the `data` value internally. This also means you have to pre-encode it:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/api/user/auth",
  data: JSON.stringify({user: jsonData}), // gotta strinigfy the entire hash
  processData: false,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    alert("You are good!");
  },
  error: function(xhr, type) {
    alert("Y U NO WORK?");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "user" key. It wasn't formatted correctly for json decode. I removed this entirely, as it wasn't necessary anyway.

So I changed:

```
data: {
    user: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
  },
```

to

```
 data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
```

And, I also implemented @air4x line:

```
$json_a = json_decode(urldecode($requestBody));
```

Comment: I think it should just be `data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)`. Objects should contain `key: value` pairs. Don't you get a syntax error from that?

Comment: yes you are correct, i forgot to remove the brackets in my answer (which i've done now). In my code I actually did write it with just  data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)